# SqliteError: database is locked while trying to run Docker Container containg Next.js application with Drizzle as an ORM?

Tags: node.js, docker, sqlite, next.js, docker-compose

I have a Next.js application that I'm trying to dockerize.

My stack is Next.js (Node.js framework) + Docker + Drizzle ORM + `better-sqlite3`

It currently works in development without docker using `pnpm db:generate` & `pnpm db:migrate:dev`. You can see the expanded commands on [my reproduction](https://github.com/deadcoder0904/easypanel-nextjs-sqlite/).

Now I'm only trying to dockerize my Next.js app for production.

However, I face an error:

```bash
42.34 SqliteError: database is locked
42.34     at Database.pragma (/app/node_modules/.pnpm/better-sqlite3@9.4.0/node_modules/better-sqlite3/lib/methods/pragma.js:11:44)
42.34     at 8699 (/app/.next/server/app/api/delete/route.js:1:1339)
42.34     at t (/app/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:127)
42.34     at 605 (/app/.next/server/app/api/delete/route.js:1:443)
42.34     at t (/app/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:127)
42.34     at r (/app/.next/server/app/api/delete/route.js:1:1558)
42.34     at /app/.next/server/app/api/delete/route.js:1:1589
42.34     at t.X (/app/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:1191)
42.34     at /app/.next/server/app/api/delete/route.js:1:1571
42.34     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/.next/server/app/api/delete/route.js:1:1615) {
42.34   code: 'SQLITE_BUSY'
```

I am trying to create a volume in production container in my `docker-compose.yml` file. Idk if I'm right though as its my first time using Docker.

#### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  docker-production:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: docker-production
    ports:
      - '3001:3000'
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
```

I copied the `Dockerfile` from the Next.js official examples.

#### Dockerfile

```dockerfile
FROM node:20-alpine AS base

# 1. Install dependencies only when needed
FROM base AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat

WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm i; \
  else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  fi


# 2. Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .
# This will do the trick, use the corresponding env file for each environment.
COPY .env.production .env.production
RUN mkdir -p /data
RUN npm run build

# 3. Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV=production

RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static


USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000
ENV HOSTNAME localhost

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

And I also have a `Makefile` to write commands in a short way.

#### Makefile

```makefile
.PHONY: build-production
build-production: ## Build the production docker image.
    docker compose -f docker-compose.yml build

.PHONY: start-production
start-production: ## Start the production docker container.
    docker compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d

.PHONY: stop-production
stop-production: ## Stop the production docker container.
    docker compose -f docker-compose.yml down
```

Now I do `make build-production` & it gives the error.

I tried using `mkdir -p /data` in Dockerfile to create `/data` folder before it starts building using `npm run build` but it doesn't work.

I have a small reproduction available at https://github.com/deadcoder0904/easypanel-nextjs-sqlite/

There are far few resources on SQLite + Docker that use an ORM to generate it.

Would love to solve this. What should I do?

I don't even know how to debug this thing. I see the Docker Logs in Docker Desktop & it shows the error happens after `npm run build`:

```bash
3.151 > next build
3.151
5.227 Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
5.227 This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
5.227 You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
5.227 https://nextjs.org/telemetry
5.227
5.352    ▲ Next.js 14.1.0
5.353    - Environments: .env.production
5.354
5.451    Creating an optimized production build ...
36.98  ✓ Compiled successfully
36.98    Linting and checking validity of types ...
41.65    Collecting page data ...
42.34 SqliteError: database is locked
.
.
.
```

How do I solve this now?

Comment: You have to create that folder, if docker will create this it will always be locked.

Comment: @TanveerAhmad how do I create it? just in my terminal using `mkdir data` on the root of the project? and then use volume mount?

Comment: exactly use mkdir to make the same folder that defines in the docker-compose file.

Comment: @TanveerAhmad i tried it & i still get similar error. my commands are in this order now: `RUN mkdir -p /data; RUN npm run db:generate; RUN npm run db:migrate:vps; RUN npm run build;` which is exactly how i do in development.

Comment: sorry, it was [ mkdir -p foldername], you can define this command in docker file

Comment: @TanveerAhmad i did. see the comment above yours has a codeblock. check the first line. i've added `;` because stackoverflow comments dont support newline but in dockerfile they are each on newline without comments. i still get database is locked error.

Comment: will I add a docker file in the answer? if you say yes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256870/discussion-between-deadcoder0904-and-tanveer-ahmad).

Comment: @Tanveer so i found the solution finally after a week haha. posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still haven't figured out to solve this error as it randomly pops-up every now & then.

It definitely is a case of 2 process accessing the same database file when its locked.

I used `@epic-web/remember` to create a singleton & used default export instead of named export to try to fix it.

I also tried to force dynamic in next.js but none of that stops that error from coming up randomly every now & then.

Anyhow, [right now my little project works & I've posted about it here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78034626/6141587)